# If Date is in 3 days then color it red

Tags: date, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am using conditional formatting in Google Sheets. However, I cannot find an option to say something like:

```
If Date is in 3 days then color it red
```

How to do the `in 3 days` in Google Sheets with conditional formatting?

Answer (score 2):

Use Date > Excact date > =today()+3

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to highlight any date in column A that is the same as a date in C1, or one or two days after C1, then you might use a conditional formatting rule of *Custom formula is*:

```
=and(A1>=$C$1,A1<$C$1+3)
```

with Background Colour: red and Range: `A:A`.